# Android correct way to draw vector with stroke width

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-drawable, vector-graphics

Hi I am trying to use a vector drawable in my android app.

Here is the xml for the same

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="1024dp"
    android:height="1024dp"
    android:viewportWidth="1024"
    android:viewportHeight="1024">
    <path
        android:pathData="M 0,0 L 50,0 L 50,50 z"
        android:strokeColor="#000000" />
</vector>
```

and here is how it looks without any stroke width
[image]

If I add **android:strokeWidth="10"** here is how it looks
[image]

The stoke width is not consistent(same width) across all lines and the leftmost point seems to be not cut off

Is there any way through which all the 3 lines drawn are of consistent(same width) and not irregular?

Comment: From what I see issue is you're drawing in the top left corner (0,0), which causes one side of the stroke to be clipped to the edge of viewport.

Comment: How to set stroke for  <clip-path> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine the drawable as a coordinate system with the point p(0,0) being on the top-left corner. Your x-axis goes from top-left to top-right and your y-axis goes from top-left to bottom-left.

When you're creating a path, it goes from one point to another point in the coordinate system. When you're stroking this path, the drawn line has some `strokeWidth` which is 1 by default. But when you set the width to, lets say 10, then the line is much thicker in your coordinate-system, but where should this "Thickness" go if your path is, for example already at y=0 ? The drawable won't display any negativate coordinates. That's why your drawable got cut-off.

The solution:
add the `strokeWidth` to the coordinates, that are smaller than `strokeWidth`  +
subtract the `strokeWidth` from the coordinates, that are greater than your `viewportWidth-strokeWidth` and/or `viewportHeight-strokeWidth` + give spacing for edges that are at the borders of your viewport (in this example a extra spacing of 3 is fine)

So your code should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="1024dp"
    android:height="1024dp"
    android:viewportWidth="1024"
    android:viewportHeight="1024">
    <path
        android:pathData="M 13,13 L 50,13 L 50,50 z"
        android:strokeColor="#000000"
        android:strokeWidth="10"/>
</vector>
```

Comment: Thanks for solution this works, was wondering if there is any generic solution which works for complex object by that what I meant was given an vector asset in xml can we use the same xml with different stroke width without changing the underlying object

Comment: How to set stroke for  <clip-path> ?